# Lost question ownership after being migrated to other site's child meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, linked-accounts

I'm a member of [Gaming.SE](//gaming.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not able to be a member of [Meta Gaming.SE](//meta.gaming.stackexchange.com). I asked a question on here and it's migrated to Meta Gaming.SE, but I cannot handle the question because it's not considered mine. I also can't login or sign up in Meta Gaming.SE because it seems I'm already a member of it.

Can anyone help me solve the problem? Previously I thought every Stack Exchange site membership means you are member of its meta too.

This is from Meta Gaming.SE:

[image: You have not asked any questions]

But I have [a migrated question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/game-stackexchangearqade-for-inside-game-questions-or-not) from here to there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an edge case of migrated questions.

If the OP doesn't already have an account on the target site, the question cannot be associated with their user.

Even if that user comes in and creates an account later on we don't have enough information from the migration to immediately associated them.

I have manually associated the question with your child-meta user.